# attribute options in foxx model

Tags: arangodb, nosql

Is there a way to specify the accepted values of the Foxx.Model?

Something like would be ideal:

```
var ExampleModel = Foxx.Model.Extend({}, 
{
    attributes: {
        field: { type: "string", required: true, values: ['one', 'two'] }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible since the last release of ArangoDB. It features the [integration of Joi into Foxx](http://docs.arangodb.org/Foxx/FoxxModel.html), so you can now do the following:

```
var Foxx = require("org/arangodb/foxx");
var joi = require("joi");

var ExampleModle = Foxx.Model.extend({
  schema: {
    field: joi.string().required().valid(['one', 'two'])
  }
});
```

See the [documentation of Joi](https://github.com/spumko/joi#anyvalidvalue) for more information.

Comment: interesting, thanks a lot, that will definitely do it